# SharePoint2013 Migration CustomSolution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am migrating from SharePoint 2007/10 to SharePoint 2013.What Is the best way to find list of SharePoint third party solutions and web parts that are present in current environment i.e SharePoint 2007/10 and what need to be installed in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following PowerShell command:

```
(Get-SPFarm).Solutions | ForEach-Object{$var = (Get-Location).Path + "\" + $_.Name; $_.SolutionFile.SaveAs($var)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Does the above command works in 2007 as well?

Comment: no, this only for 2013/2010 as it is in powershell. you get the similar command in STSADM or look at the central administration under farm solutions.

Comment: thank you....please Can any one Share the STSADM command, for third party farm solutions in MOSS 2007.